# How can I create a Zombie process in Windows?

Tags: windows, process, zombie-process

How can I create a Zombie process in Windows? Is there a tool to see all zombie processes?

Comment: After a process exits, the kernel Process object is kept alive by handle references. This allows querying the exit status and other statistics. It won't appear in task lists since a terminated process is removed from the kernel's active list. Why do you need to see terminated processes?

Comment: Is there a way to figure out which process is a zombie process?

Comment: If you have a handle to a process that's terminated, it's a 'zombie'. The process isn't holding resources anymore. Its handle table and virtual memory are freed. The object is only kept around for bookkeeping. I don't see why it's of interest to find terminated process objects. At any rate, probably it can only be accomplished by writing a kernel driver and accessing undocumented structures directly.